# Remove space over navigation bar

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

I got this view with a navigation controller. But there is some space between the navigation and the top of the screen. I don't want to hide the status/top bar, just on top (see screenshots). How to fill the rest out?

Thanks!!

[image: The space i want to fill out]

[image: How i want it]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to change your -info.plist file and to set value of key “View controller-based status bar appearance” to NO.

For more details about it, you can check this link:
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/